# Create cookie on domain that is other than parent page in ITP enabled Safari browser

Tags: cookies

**Use case:**

Two separate websites and does NOT share any common domain or sub-domain.

A.com is one web site

B.com is other one .

In A.com , under iframe B.com page is loaded .

B.com script needs to create cookie under b.com domain. This is working fine other than Safari 12 browser.

Safari has ITP 2.1 policy which prevents cookie creation other than parent page domain.
If I visit B.com  explicitly in browser and then it allows to create cookie.

I do not have control over server side code. any client side option to workaround that mimic that user has visited B.com ?

posting fake form to b.com from iframe

or

Does 302 redirect work? ( create url 
www.B.com?redirect=a.com which redirect back to a and in response ask browser to set cookie)

does it allows only HTTPonly cookie from server side response?

Any input on this will be great.